# move app that uses rewrite rules in .htaccess to a sub-directory

Tags: mod-rewrite, apache-2.2

how do i move a web app that uses rewrite rules and lives in the root of the web server to a sub-directory?

i have an app running on my apache web server that uses the following rewrite rules in an .htaccess file:

```
RewriteCond $1 !^(tool|web|files)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !((.*)\.(.*))$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ dispatcher.php?route=/$1 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^(img|css|js)/(.*) web/$1/$2 [L,QSA]
```

the app currently lives in the root of the web server. i want to move it to a sub-directory but when i do the app no longer works. i tried adding `RewriteBase /newdir` but that only makes the main pages work and not the css/img/js directories.

ideally, i'd like to NOT change the existing rules but instead add an additional rule.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, I think the RewriteBase /newdir is right, that would apply your rules in the new directory, the rule works fine.

Second, you may need to remove the caret (^) character from the last rule, something like this should work.

RewriteRule ^(.*)/(img|css|js)/(.*) web/$2/$3 [L,QSA]